# Boolean method which returns true if a subarray sums to num

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need to write a recursive, boolean method which receives a 1d array and a number num.
The method checks if a subarray whose length is equal to or less than 3 and it's elements can be summed to num, in a few conditions:

1. the numbers are non consecutive.

2.cannot use the same number twice.

Examples:
array: `{5,4,2,1,3}`, number = 9 - returns true because 4+5 = 9.
This one is valid as 4,5 are consecutive but it's not a triplet of numbers.

number = 8 - returns true because 5+3 = 8, 4 + 3 + 1 = 8.

number = 11 - returns false because 5+4+2 = 11 but elements are consecutive.

Below is what I've written so far:

```
  public static boolean isSum(int[]a,int num){
    return isSum(a,0,0,0,num);
}
private static boolean isSum(int[]a, int i, int sum,int counter,int num){
    if(i > a.length - 1 || a[i] == -1||counter > 3){
        return false;
    }
    if(sum == num&& !(sum == a[i] + a[i+1] + a[i+2] || sum == a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1] || sum == 
                                                                       a[i-2] + a[i-1] +a[i])){
        return true;
    }
    int k = a[i];
    a[i] = -1;

    boolean notused = isSum(a, i+1, sum, counter, num);
    boolean used = isSum(a,i+1,sum+a[i],counter +1, num);
    
    a[i] = k;
    return used||notused;
   
}
```

The logic is as following: the method either takes the current element and adds it to sum, or it skips is. every time we take an element we add 1 to counter, and then we turn the element we've used to -1 in order to not use it again.
the method will return true only if sum == num and sum != 3 consecutive order numbers.

This method returns only false. any idea why?

Comment: `any idea why?` place a breakpoints around return statements and step over your program with debugger, you will found out

Comment: thanks @user16320675 I've edited my question.